# The validation in api doesn't work in postman for my laravel project

Tags: laravel

I try to put a validation in a single-action controller and test the API in postman, but it doesn't show anything.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class BookableAvailabilityController extends Controller
{

public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
       $data = $request->validate([
         'from' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:now',
         'to' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:from',
]); 
 }
 }
```

and I defined the route in API file:

```
Route::get('bookables/{bookable}/availability', 'Api\BookableAvailabilityController')
```

The route is right as it is shown in the route:list

[image]

But the postman show the code 200 says everything is OK

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO ... laravel approach for validation is make `Request` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation  or `$this->validate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request->validate` method, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user. In the case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be generated, while a JSON response will be sent for AJAX requests.

You can use Validator function .so that you can pass custom response

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
      'from' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:now',
         'to' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:from',
  ]);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
  }
```

Comment: Thx so much, solved it. This is my first time using Stackoverflow, really found it useful and efficient thanks to guys like you!

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines after the validator. Errors will be listed out in postman.

if ($validator->fails()) {
$message = $validator->errors();
return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'The given data was invalid.', 'errors' => $validator->errors()], 200);
}